Angular - How to work with value 0 in @if template flow syntax
I have a problem with @if in the Angular template flow syntax.
A value is available in an RxJs Observable. So the async pipe helps and the value is assigned to a variable.
@if (currentPageNumber$ | async; as currentPageNumber) {
// currentPageNumber is number

For value 0 the if statement is not valid. So I exclude only null values... but now the value of currentPageNumber is boolean.
@if ((currentPageNumber$ | async) !== null; as currentPageNumber) {
// currentPageNumber is boolean

How can I check against null but keep my variable with the value of the stream?

You can wrap the value directly in the template, this is probably the most straight forward way knowing how the AsyncPipe works.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
  template: `
    @if({value: (sub$ | async)}; as wrappedValue) {
      foo {{wrappedValue.value}}
    } @else {
      bar
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  sub$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);
}


Would probably work but still looks a bit awkward. I would say with ngIf this was possbile in a straight forward way.

What it really, though ?

Shame on me - I relied on answers from Copilot. But I tried it and I'm (and Copilot is) wrong. The problem is the same with the classic ngIf directive. (btw much respect for your work. I knew your blog page before.)

Looks like a limitation of the @if syntax (0 evaluates to false in JS so you can't use the syntax), you can just workaround it, by setting the value to string '0' but you need to take care of converting it back to number using +
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
  template: `
    @if (check(currentPageNumber$ | async); as currentPageNumber) {
      {{+currentPageNumber}}
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  currentPageNumber$ = of(0);

  check(value: any) {
    return value === 0 ? '0' : value;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Doing 2 async is really a bad practice. You're subscribing twice.

@MatthieuRiegler fixed it, check now!

If you are not a fan of having nested if-s in the template you can use the following approach (like the approach shared by jeremy-denis).
Here I'm modifying the response so that it is no longer a "falsy" value, so once the | async is evaluated to "truthy" value you will get the block below rendered and you can you the users reference to access the number.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
      <pre>{{str$ | async | json}}</pre>
      @if (str$ | async; as users) {
           {{users | json}}   
      }
  `,
})
export class App {
  str$ = of(0).pipe(
    /// the delay will result in `null` value for the first 2sec
    delay(2000),
    map((x) => {
      // mutate the response to something that is not null and store the value
      return  {
        pageSize: 0
      };
    })
  );
}

